# Android 7 - Multi-Window Support(2 apps on screen)

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

Do I need to write some extra code in my Android application to support Multi-Window Applications?

Comment: If by "support Multi-Window Applications", you mean "allow my activities to appear in windows", then no, by default, this happens automatically. You have to take special steps to try to *prevent* your activities from appearing in windows.

Comment: With only half of the screen available you should probably have to adapt some layouts.

Comment: Check Google developer website before asking question https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html